# Invoke power shell script on remote windows server

Tags: java, powershell

I have a power shell script resides on a remote computer and I want to invoke it. The Windows server machines sitting on a WSUS server.
I need a Java code snippet that can execute it.
Here are the code snippets I tried (after enabling PSRemote):
As you can see I tried many ways to attack the issue but non of them helped.

```
public class PowerShellRunner {

    private PowerShellRunner(){

    }
    public static void run1 (String ip) {
        try {
            ProcessBuilder launcher = new ProcessBuilder();
            Map<String, String> environment = launcher.environment();
            launcher.redirectErrorStream(true);
            launcher.directory(new File("\\\\255.255.255.255\\C$\\\\"));
            launcher.command("powershell.exe", "install-patch-on-computer.ps1");
            Process p = launcher.start(); // And launch a new process
            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
                    InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            System.out.println("Output :");
            while ((line = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void run2() throws IOException
    {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = new ProcessBuilder()
                .inheritIO()
                .command("powershell", "invoke-command", "-computername", "255.255.255.255",
                        "-filepath", "C$\\install-patch-on-computer.ps1").start();

        InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        reader.close();
        proc.getOutputStream().close();
    }

    public static void run4() throws IOException {
        try {
            String command = "\\\\255.255.255.255\\C$\\install-patch-on-computer.ps1";
            ExecuteWatchdog watchdog = new ExecuteWatchdog(20000);
            Process powerShellProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            if (watchdog != null) {
                watchdog.start(powerShellProcess);
            }
            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(powerShellProcess.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            System.out.println("Output :");
            while ((line = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void run5() throws IOException
    {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = runtime.exec("powershell \\\\255.255.255.255\\C$\\install-patch-on-computer.ps1");
        InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        reader.close();
        proc.getOutputStream().close();
    }

}
```

```
Here is the output of running the runs methods:

run result
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "powershell.exe" (in directory "\\172.16.1.67\C:"): CreateProcess error=267, The directory name is invalid
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at com.intigua.automation.jet_patch.end_points.winows.PowerShellRunner.run(PowerShellRunner.java:22)
    at com.intigua.jet_patch.RailRunnerTest.before(RailRunnerTest.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=267, The directory name is invalid
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 17 more
run2 result
run4 result
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "\\172.16.1.67\C$\install-patch-on-computer.ps1": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:347)
    at com.intigua.automation.jet_patch.end_points.winows.PowerShellRunner.run4(PowerShellRunner.java:73)
    at com.intigua.jet_patch.RailRunnerTest.before(RailRunnerTest.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 20 more
run5 result
invoke-command : Cannot find path 
'C:\Users\asih\IdeaProjects\patch_core_verification\C$\install-patch-on-computer.ps1' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ invoke-command -computername 172.16.1.67 -filepath C$\install-patch-o ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\asih\I...on-computer.ps1:String) [Invoke-Command], ItemNotFoun 
   dException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
```

Comment: `invoke-command -computername 172.16.1.67 -filepath C$\install-patch-...` -> `Invoke-Command -Computer 172.16.1.67 -Scriptblock {& C:\install-patch-...}`

Comment: Are you sure it is a legal Java  path? I tried  Process proc = runtime.exec("powershell invoke-command -computername 172.16.1.67 -filepath C$\\install-patch-install-patch-on-computer.ps1 -> Invoke-Command -Computer 172.16.1.67 -Scriptblock {& C:\\install-patch-install-patch-on-computer.ps1}"); and gives the same results...

Comment: The arrow in my comment means that you're supposed to replace the former PowerShell command with the latter. `C$\install-patch-on-computer.ps1` is not a valid (local) path, and the parameter `-FilePath` is for running a script from your *local* computer on a remote computer. For running a script from a remote computer on that remote computer you need the `-Scriptblock` parameter.

Comment: It worked, thanks man it really helped...I get authenticaion error but probably I can fix it with -user -password in the script...Or the authentication ocours in earlier stages?

Comment: Still have authentication issue I run                                 
command("powershell", "invoke-command", "-computer", "255.255.255.1",
                        "-username", "user", "-password", "password",
                        "-Scriptblock" ,"{& C:\\install-patch-on-computer.ps1}").start(); And getting  :                                                                                               
 Invoke-Command : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'username'.

Comment: `Invoke-Command` doesn't have parameters `-Username` or `-Password`. The parameter you're looking for is `-Credential` and it expects a `PSCredential` object that you need to create first.